# why was k8s service deleted but the cluster IP works still

Tags: kubernetes, service

I can easily reporduce this and could not find an answer for this issue either in k8s doc or the community.

Simple reproduce steps:

1. create service and endpoint with below config

```
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: hostname
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 9376

---
kind: Endpoints
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: hostname
subsets:
  - addresses:
      - ip: 10.244.44.250
      - ip: 10.244.154.235
    ports:
      - port: 9376
```

2. `kubectl apply -f <filename>` to apply the config
3. test the service and it works perfect. Assume the cluster IP is A
4. `kubectl delete -f <filename>` to delete the service and endpoint and `kubectl apply -f <filename>` again
5. we got another cluser IP B, which works perfect also
6. however, cluser IP A was not removed as expected. I can use A to access the service still.
7. Update the endpoint definition (add new endpoint IP or remove one) and apply, B sees the change while A uses old config still.

Is there someone can explain what happens there?

My k8s version is:

```
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"15", GitVersion:"v1.15.1", GitCommit:"4485c6f18cee9a5d3c3b4e523bd27972b1b53892", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-07-18T09:09:21Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Comment: You are using local kubernetes? How your cluster was created? If you are using cloud provider, what?

Comment: @mWatney right, I am using local deployed k8s, three VM master nodes and 2 PM worker node. But does this matter?

Comment: kubeadm, kubesparay, the-hard-way?

Comment: @mWatney we use kubeadm. If I got you correctly, do you mean this is not a generic issue while I can easily reproduce it?

Comment: I tested and I don't have the same behavior. Have you reproduced it on a different cluster?

Comment: I have no chance to test this in another working env yet, will build such one soon.